# What does the @ symbol in '@*/grunt-*' glob pattern mean?

Tags: gruntjs

What does the `@` symbol in `'@*/grunt-*'` glob pattern mean?

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {pattern: ['grunt-*', '@*/grunt-*']});
```

From load-grunt-tasks (https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) doc.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` isn't some weird glob syntax - it's just matching directories that begin with `@`.

That particular glob pattern was added so that [scoped NPM packages are supported](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks/commit/00ee3bac134b162c0d1612f049644d88211bcc87) - package scopes are prefixed with `@`.